# Problema com retorno de vetor em c++

Tags: array, c++

Eu estou tentando fazer um programinha para ordenar vetor e estou usando uma função auxiliar para fazer isso, mas está me voltando essa mensagem de erro.

```
/media/isaque/dados/exercicios/c/scripts/estrutura de dados com c++/busca_binaria.cpp: In function ‘void ordenar_vetor(int*)’:
/media/isaque/dados/exercicios/c/scripts/estrutura de dados com c++/busca_binaria.cpp:38:7: warning: variable ‘aux’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int aux;
```

esse é meu script

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#define TAM 15

int main()
{
  void ordenar_vetor(int *vetor);
  int gerar_aleatorio();

  int valores[TAM];

  for(int c = 0; c < TAM; c++ )
  {
    valores[c] = gerar_aleatorio();
  }

  ordenar_vetor(valores);

  for(int c = 0; c < TAM; c++ )
  {
    std::cout << valores[c] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}



int gerar_aleatorio()
{
  std::random_device m;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> gerar(1,100);
  return gerar(m);
}

void ordenar_vetor(int *vetor)
{
  int aux;

  for(int c = 0; c < TAM; c++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; c++)
    {
      if(vetor[c] < vetor[i])
      {
        aux = vetor[i];
        vetor[i] = vetor[c];
        vetor[c] = vetor[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

não to conseguindo identificar aonde eu estou errando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois erros no final. Você deu um valor a `aux`, mas nunca usou. Também está aumentando `c` nos dois laços `for`, quando deve aumentar `i` no segundo laço. Eu acho que você queria:

```
for(int c = 0; c < TAM; c++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[c] < vetor[i])
        {
            aux = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[c];
            vetor[c] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

O código original daria o valor de `vetor[c]` a `vetor[i]`, mas não mudaria o valor de `vetor[c]`, porque `vetor[i]` já mudou. Usando `aux` guarda o valor de `vetor[i]` para mudar o valor de `vetor[c]` corretamente.

Também, no código original, `i` sempre tem um valor `0`, então o laço interior nunca termina.

Comment: nossa verdade, falta de atenção minha, porém agora estou com outro problema, quando eu deixo comentado a chamada da função "ordenar_vetor" ele funciona normal, mas quando eu chamo a função ele simplesmente não faz nada.

Comment: Tente mover a declaração de `ordenar_vetor` em cima de `main`. Agora você está declarando dentro de `main`.

Comment: Errei. Acabei de ver que tem um erro no `for` loop. No primeiro está usando `c` e no segundo está usando `i`, mas no segundo está aumentando `c` quando deve aumentar `i`.

Comment: nossa é mesmo, obrigado!!